# Combinacion de estilos SweetAlert2 al momento de sacar diferentes modals en el mismo formulario realiza una conbinacion de estilos

Tags: sweetalert2

`const NotificationOK = Swal.mixin({`
`showCloseButton: true,`
`focusConfirm: true,`
`allowOutsideClick: false,`
`allowEscapeKey: false,`
`confirmButtonText: 'OK',`
`confirmButtonColor: '#181933' });`

Instancia para el Modal de Carga

`const ModalLoading = Swal.mixin({title: "",allowOutsideClick: false,allowEscapeKey: false,didOpen: () => { Swal.showLoading();}});`

`function modalLoading(titulo) {ModalLoading.fire({html: titulo});}`

`function notificacionok(mensaje) {NotificationOK = null;NotificationOK.fire({html: mensaje});}`

[image: modal de cargando]

[image: Este deberia se el modal de notificacionOK]